# Cannot get response body from POST request python

Tags: python, post, request, response

I am trying to write simple aplication in python who will send some text to server using POST HTTP method and then get response containing some text.

Server:

```
from http.server import *
class MyServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_POST(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type","text/plain")
        self.end_headers()
        print(self.rfile.read().decode("UTF-8"))
        self.wﬁle.write(bytes("TEST RESPONSE", "UTF-8"))

address = ("",8000)
httpd = HTTPServer(address, MyServer)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Client:

```
import http.client
class client:
    def __init__(self):
        h = self.request("127.0.0.1:8000", "POST", "OH YEA")
        resp = h.getresponse()
        print(resp.status)
        #data = resp.read()


    def request(self, host, metoda, strona):
        headers = { "Host" : host, "Accept": r"text/plain" }
        h = http.client.HTTPConnection(host)
        h.request(metoda,"",strona,headers)
        return h

a = client()
```

Well as long as line data = resp.read() remains commented everything works fine (well server get request prints to the console body of it and sends response) but when i try to read response body server does not print request body and i don't get and even if i get response status 200 i cannot read response body (well whole aplication "hangs up"). What am I doing wrong? I am guessing that behevior of server has something to do with not finished response procesing but i cannot finish it cuz i can't get response body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `Content-Length` header on your HTTP response. The HTTP client does not know when the response is complete, so it keeps on waiting for more.:

```
def do_POST(self):
    content = bytes("TEST RESPONSE", "UTF-8")
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type","text/plain")
    self.send_header("Content-Length", len(content))
    self.end_headers()
    print(self.rfile.read().decode("UTF-8"))
    self.wfile.write(content)
```

This does not completely work, yet: the server has the same problem: it just keeps on reading from the `rfile`.

```
def do_POST(self):
    content = bytes("TEST RESPONSE", "UTF-8")
    self.send_response(200)
    self.send_header("Content-type","text/plain")
    self.send_header("Content-Length", len(content))
    self.end_headers()
    print(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-Length'])).decode("UTF-8"))
    self.wfile.write(content)
```

Using curl, this works fine:

```
$ curl -X POST http://localhost:8000 -d 'testrequest'
TEST RESPONSE
```

There are ways to do this without a `Content-Length` header, but for the beginning, this should be enough.

**Edit**: this is a nice exercise in writing a HTTP client/server, but for production usage, you might want to consider more high-level abstractions, like [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) for the client side and [WSGI](http://docs.python.org/3/library/wsgiref.html) or a full web framework for the server side ([Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/) or [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) are popular choices, depending on your requirements).

Comment: My god man i am lovin ya :) Cuz of http://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html i thought Content-Length is set automaticaly. Now it of course works :) Thank you so much :) Btw: Merry Christmas and Happy New Year!!!

Comment: Thank you :-) I might be wrong about `Content-Length` from the client, did you try it without manually setting it? I just looked at the documentation, and it _should_ work :-) Btw. [this is the documentation for Python 3.x](http://docs.python.org/3/library/http.html), you were reading the 2.x version